# How to handle missing fields in a PowerBI custom data connector?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-datasource

I'm trying to create a custom PowerBI connector over a REST web service that returns a paginated set of records (similar to the OData nextLink pattern).  The service omits null values for fields that have no values, so some records may have more or less fields than other records.

For example, I might get back:

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "next_link": "...",
  "value": [
    {
      "first": "John",
      "last": "Doe"
    },
    {
      "first": "Jame",
      "middle": "S",
      "last": "Doe"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've implemented the pagination mechanism from the DataConnectors [TripPin repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/DataConnectors/tree/master/samples/TripPin) (using the helper function Table.GenerateByPage), but when I view the list of records I see errors on rows that have missing fields. 
The errors are of the form:

```
Expression.Error: The field 'middle' of the record wasn't found.
Details:
    first=Jane
    last=Doe
```

According to the [docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/DataConnectors/blob/master/docs/helper-functions.md):  "the columns and table type of the combined table (i.e. all pages together) are derived from the first page of data."  But in the above example, the first page of data contains a record that doesn't have a "middle" name field.

I understand the error, but am not sure how to handle this in my data connector. 
 I'd like the resulting Table in PowerBI to use "null" for any missing values.  How can I modify the Table.GenerateByPage to normalize the concatenated lists using null for any missing fields?  Or is there a more preferred way of handling this type of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to enforce a schema on the data as per the 7th in the series of TripPin tutorials: https://github.com/Microsoft/DataConnectors/tree/master/samples/TripPin/7-AdvancedSchema

This does work - I recently implemented Microsoft's example on a generic REST API here: https://github.com/GrantQuick/BlackbaudSkyApi